# Creating first user in MongoDB 3.2.

Tags: mongodb, permissions, admin

I newly installed MongoDB 3.2 and tried to create the first user which throws the following error.

" Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command"

I followed mongoDB 3.2 documentation,
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

To add the administrator, I tried the following code which results in the above error

Create the user administrator.
Add a user with the userAdminAnyDatabase role. For example, the following creates the user myUserAdmin on the admin database:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "MY_PASSWORD",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

I gone through the other stackoverflow answers as well like but with no luck,

[MongoDB - admin user not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized)

[Update role user: not authorized on admin to execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324901/update-role-user-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command)

My full error,

```
 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser: "myUserAdmin
", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 30000.0
} } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1225:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you re-use an existing [database directory](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) `/data/db`, it is likely that previously there's already a user/auth set up.

You could either:

- Start with a new database directory by pointing to a new data directory using [--dbpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory).
- Run `mongod` without `--auth`, then

  ```
  use admin;
  db.getUsers(); // to see whether there's already an existing user.
  ```

  Use [db.removeUser()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.removeUser/) to remove existing users.

Comment: after I execute `db.getUsers()` I get Error: not authorized on admin to execute command